# MPI_Scatterv from Intel MPI (mpiifort) using MPI data types is much slower (23 times) compared to flattening array and scattering. Why it could be?

Tags: fortran, mpi, distributed-computing, intel-oneapi, intel-mpi

ifort version: (IFORT) 2021.8.0 20221119
OS: WSL Ubuntu 20.04LTS

1. I have a (1000x1000x1000) 3D array to distribute among procs. In the first approach, I flatten the array and then distribute arrays among procs and it takes about 7.86sec
2. In the second approach I use MPI-derived data types to Scatterv the 3D array and I noticed that it takes about 165.34sec. But Gatherv of the same data took about 14.24 sec.
3. What could be the reason for this inconsistency? I expected Scatterv to take similar time as Gatherv

Here is the code

```cpp
program ex_scatterv
use mpi
use iso_fortran_env, only : real64
implicit none

!allocate arrays
real(real64), allocatable,dimension(:,:,:) :: array, array_local
real(real64), allocatable,dimension(:) :: array_flat, array_local_flat
integer :: rank, num_procs, i, j, k
integer :: nx, ny, nz, str_idx, end_idx, local_size, local_size_flat
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: sendcounts, displacements
integer :: sizes(3), sub_sizes(3), starts(3), recv_starts(3), recv_sizes(3), &
send_type, resize_send_type, recv_type, resize_recv_type
integer(kind=8) :: lb, extent, lb_resize
real(real64) :: start_time
integer :: mpierr
call mpi_init(mpierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, num_procs, mpierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, rank, mpierr)

!size of array
nx=1000
ny=1000
nz=1000

if(rank==0) then
if(num_procs>nx) then
print*, "Number of procs should be less than or equal to first dimension of the array"
call MPI_Abort(mpi_comm_world, 1, mpierr)
endif
endif

start_time=MPI_Wtime()
!allocate in the root rank
if(rank==0) then
allocate(array(nx,ny,nz))
allocate(array_flat(nx*ny*nz))
else !for other procs allocate with zero size
allocate(array(0,0,0))
endif

!assign values to the array
if(rank==0) then
do k=1,nz
do j=1,ny
do i=1,nx
array(i,j,k) = (i-1)+(j-1)*nx+(k-1)*nx*ny
end do
end do
end do
!print*, "Before scattering..."
!print*, array
!flatten the 3D array
forall(k=1:nz, j=1:ny, i=1:nx) array_flat(k+(j-1)*nz+(i-1)*ny*nz)=array(i,j,k)
endif

!distribute the 3d array among different procs
call distribute_points(nx, rank, num_procs, str_idx, end_idx)
local_size = end_idx - str_idx + 1
local_size_flat = local_size*ny*nz

!allocate local(for each rank) arrays
allocate(array_local_flat(local_size_flat))
allocate(array_local(local_size, ny, nz))

!allocate sendcoutns and displacements arrays for braodcasting
allocate(sendcounts(num_procs), displacements(num_procs))

!gather displacements and sendcounts for all ranks
call MPI_Allgather(str_idx, 1, MPI_INTEGER, displacements, 1, MPI_INTEGER, &
MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)
call MPI_Allgather(local_size, 1, MPI_INTEGER, sendcounts, 1, &
MPI_INTEGER, MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)

!total sendcounts and displacements
sendcounts = sendcounts*ny*nz
displacements = displacements - 1 !Array index starts with 0 in MPI (C)
displacements = displacements*ny*nz

!scatter the flattened array among procs
call MPI_Scatterv(array_flat, sendcounts, displacements, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
array_local_flat, local_size*ny*nz, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
mpierr)

!form 3D array from flattened local array
forall(k=1:nz, j=1:ny, i=1:local_size) array_local(i,j,k) = &
array_local_flat(k+(j-1)*nz+(i-1)*ny*nz)

!print*, "Scattered array: ", rank
!print*, array_local
if(rank==0) then
print*, "Time taken by flatten and scatter: ", MPI_Wtime()-start_time
endif

call MPI_Barrier(mpi_comm_world, mpierr)
!deallocate(array_flat, array_local_flat)

start_time=MPI_Wtime()
!Scatterning using subarray type
sizes = [nx, ny, nz]
recv_sizes=[local_size, ny, nz]
sub_sizes = [1, ny, nz]
starts = [0, 0, 0]
recv_starts = [0, 0, 0]

!to get extent of MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
call MPI_Type_get_extent(MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, lb, extent, mpierr)

!create a mpi subarray data type for sending data
call MPI_Type_create_subarray(3, sizes, sub_sizes, starts, &
MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, send_type, mpierr)
lb_resize=0
!resize the send subarray for starting at correct location for next send
call MPI_Type_create_resized(send_type, lb_resize, extent, &
resize_send_type, mpierr)
call MPI_Type_commit(resize_send_type, mpierr)

!create a mpi subarray data type for receiving data
call MPI_Type_create_subarray(3, recv_sizes, sub_sizes, recv_starts, &
MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, recv_type, mpierr)

!resize the receive subarray for starting at correct location for next receive
call MPI_Type_create_resized(recv_type, lb_resize, extent, &
resize_recv_type, mpierr)
call MPI_Type_commit(resize_recv_type, mpierr)

!sendcounts and displacement for sending and receiving subarrays
sendcounts=sendcounts/(ny*nz)
displacements = displacements/(ny*nz)

if(rank==0) then
print*, "Time taken for creating MPI type subarrays: ", MPI_Wtime()-start_time
endif

call MPI_Barrier(mpi_comm_world, mpierr)
start_time=MPI_Wtime()
!scatter the subarrays
call MPI_Scatterv(array, sendcounts, displacements, resize_send_type, &
array_local, sendcounts, resize_recv_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)

if(rank==0) then
print*, "Time taken for scattering using MPI type subarrays: ", MPI_Wtime()-start_time
endif
call MPI_Barrier(mpi_comm_world, mpierr)
!print the scattered array
!print*, "Scattered array with subarray: ", rank
!print*, array_local

!do some computations on the scattered local arrays
array_local = array_local+1

call MPI_Barrier(mpi_comm_world, mpierr)
start_time=MPI_Wtime()
!Gather the local arrays to global (array) using the same subarrays
call MPI_Gatherv(array_local, local_size, resize_recv_type, array, &
sendcounts, displacements, resize_send_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)

if(rank==0) then
print*, "Time taken by MPI_Type_create_subarray Gathering: ", MPI_Wtime()-start_time
endif

!if(rank==0) then
! print*, "Gathered array: ------------------"
! print*, array
!endif
call MPI_Finalize(mpierr)

 

contains

subroutine distribute_points(npts, rank, size, start_idx, end_idx)
implicit none

integer, intent(in) :: npts, size, rank
integer, intent(out) :: start_idx, end_idx
integer :: pts_per_proc

pts_per_proc = npts/size

if(rank < mod(npts, size)) then
pts_per_proc=pts_per_proc + 1
end if

if(rank < mod(npts, size)) then
start_idx = rank * pts_per_proc + 1
end_idx = (rank + 1) * pts_per_proc
else
start_idx = mod(npts, size) + rank*pts_per_proc + 1
end_idx = mod(npts, size) + (rank + 1) * pts_per_proc
end if

end subroutine distribute_points


end program ex_scatterv
```

Comment: It is tangetial, but for such huge working arrays, I would strongly reconsider the program design. Do you really need the data to be all at one rank at any given time? All processes should normally work on their own part of the data if at all possible. That includes input and output of data files. Any computer can fit 8GB these days but one should consider scalability to larger problems and communication time.

Comment: MPI implementations typically "flatten" the buffers under the hood, and this is generally a serial process. If your Fortran compiler chose to use several cores in order to implement the `forall`, that could explain why using derived datatypes is slower.

Comment: I'd also note that if the efficiency of your implementation is strongly dependent on a scatter(v) operation it is inherently non-scalable. See @VladimirFГероямслава 's comment. Also, some indentation, please!

Comment: `forall` is best avoided altogether - it is obsolescent as of Fortran 2018.

Comment: I agree with you all on the scaling part. I was trying to benchmark these. My arrays are not that big. And also since I am parallelizing serial code. I am starting in between and eventually will remove these scatter and gathering ops.

Comment: Not sure that an array of size 1000x1000x1000 (8 GB to store double precision) can be described as "not that big" !

Comment: 1B is big. I meant the arrays in my project aren't the size of 1B!

Comment: *"I have a (1000x1000x1000) 3D array"*, this is really 8GB large

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why MPI datatypes can be slower than a user-level pack-and-send operation.

I have explored this in https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10778

- Data types, unlike plain buffers, are not streamed straight from memory: they are read, written to a compact buffer, and then again read for sending. (If you have expensive network cards they may actually stream straight from memory, but don't count on that.) So there can be a bandwidth penalty on using derived types.
- MPI may not send the whole message at once, for instance because it is reluctant to create really big internal buffers.
- If you do your sends in a timing loop, you run into the fact that MPI is stateless, so it will repeatedly allocate and free its internal buffers.

In your specific case, the irregularity of your data, as pointed out by several commenters may also make your `Scatterv` inefficient.

Comment: Very useful reference. Thanks.